# My PanGestureRecognizer won't move when i want to resize it

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I Have a UIPanGestureRecognizer. It works fine. I made an if statement so when someone touches the picture, it will be alpha 0.7 and it will be 1,5 times bigger. The alpha works fine, but when i type in the CAAffineTransformMakeScale method, my image won't move.

this is my code:

```
- (IBAction)Bloemen:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

     if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

        bloemen.alpha = 0.7f;
        bloemen.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
     }
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];

        bloemen.alpha = 1.0f;
        bloemen.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

       [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
}
```

Comment: If you're using autolayout, I can show you how to animate the changing of constraints (because the moved view will return to its original location when constraints are reapplied, such as when you do your final animation), but don't want to cloud the issue unless you're using autolayout. The key issue in the above code snippet rests in the `if` clauses, as discussed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical issue is that your `if` statements are not checking the `state` property. It should be:

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    // began code here
}
else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    // ended code here
}
```

Also be aware that this gesture recognizer will only work if you have autolayout turned off. If you're using autolayout, you have to change the constraints.

---

If you forgive the stylistic observations, I might also be inclined to suggest:

- use block-based animations;
- not reference non-local variables if not needed (i.e. reference `recognizer.view` rather than `bloemen`), which makes it easier to reuse this handler for dragging and dropping of various `UIView` objects you choose to add this gesture to; and
- use standard naming conventions, start method names with lowercase letter and follow the `verbNoun` convention.

None of this is critical and please use or disregard as you see fit, but this exhibits a few best practices:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{    
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                              delay:0.0  // you had 0.1, but seems worthwhile to give immediate feedback
                            options:0
                         animations:^{
                             recognizer.view.alpha = 0.7f;
                             recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                              delay:0.0  // you had 0.1, but seems worthwhile to give immediate feedback
                            options:0
                         animations:^{
                             recognizer.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                             recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```